# RealTime Database with Flutter overwrites data instead of adding it to the existing nodes

Tags: json, firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I am using flutter with Firebase Realtime Database. As shown in the code, each user can create his lists and add tasks to it. However, every time I try to add a new task to the same list it overwrites the existing data instead of appending to it. Can someone please help me out.

This is the ToDo model

```
class Todo {
  String group;
  String subject;
  bool completed;
  String userId;

  Todo(this.userId, this.group, this.subject, this.completed);

  Todo.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
      : group = snapshot.value["group"],
        userId = snapshot.value["userId"],
        subject = snapshot.value["subject"],
        completed = snapshot.value["completed"];

  toJson() {
    return {
      userId: {
        "lists": [
          {
            "groupname": group,
            "tasks": [
              {"name": subject, "done": completed},
            ]
          },
        ]
      }
    };
  }
}
```

This is the function to add to the database

```
addNewTodo(String groupn, String taskn) {
    if (groupn.length > 0 && taskn.length > 0) {
      Todo todo =
          new Todo(widget.userId, groupn.toString(), taskn.toString(), false);
      _database.reference().child("Todo").set(todo.toJson());
    }
  }
```

groupn & taskn are the variables inputted by the user.

Comment: Hello there. `set()`, as the name suggests, sets the value of the child as what you specified, which is essentially an update if the child already exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`push()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/DatabaseReference/push.html) to append data under your child.

You'd need to remove current data under "Todo" child for sanity, since your structure of data would change to something of this format:

```
Todo
  |-> "UniqueID1"
  |     |-> Todo Details (JSON)
  |
  |-> "UniqueID2"
  |     |-> Todo Details (JSON)
  |
  |-> ...
```

`UniqueIDX` is an alphanumeric string generated by Firebase every time you `push()` OR add an Todo.

You can use [`onChildAdded`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/firebase_database/Query/onChildAdded.html) to listen for data.

Comment: Please mark as accepted if the answer was helpful, thanks!